# Prolog replying with a string that looks like a memory location not the variable content

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog. I have been trying to figure out why i keep getting the following output:

```
What is your name:
|: Jake.
 Hello, _L142
 true.
```

from the following code:

```
go:-
    write('What is your name:'),nl,
    read(MyNameIs),
    write('Hello, '),write(MyNameIs),nl.
```

I thought that the _L142 is meant to write back the name that I have just typed that is Jake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` is actually a parser for Prolog terms, so it treats `Jake` (initial capital!) as a Prolog variable. This is unified with a fresh, internal variable `_L142` and that in turn is printed.

Either type your name with a lowercase letter, single-quote it, or use another I/O mechanism than `read`.

Comment: aaaahhh, right. Thanks that makes sense. so I should always use an Atom or quote the string.